# Trying to upload CSV with some emtpy fields to MySQL DB with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv, crud

I've been trying to create this function to upload data on my MySQL database (for now on my localhost), some fields in the CSV files will always come empty and I believe is the reason for the error as i try to upload the file with no blank spaces and works perfect, here the code top upload the CSV file

```
<?php

include('conexion.php');

$fileContacts = $_FILES['fileContacts']; 
$fileContacts = file_get_contents($fileContacts['tmp_name']); 

$fileContacts = explode("\n", $fileContacts);
$fileContacts = array_filter($fileContacts); 

// preparar contactos (convertirlos en array)
foreach ($fileContacts as $contact) 
{
    $contactList[] = explode(",", $contact);
}

// insertar contactos
foreach ($contactList as $contactData) 
{
    $conexion->query("INSERT INTO contacts 
                        (contact_given_name,
                         contact_last_name,
                         contact_phone,
                         contact_email,
                         contact_zip_code)
                         VALUES

                         ('{$contactData[0]}',
                          '{$contactData[1]}', 
                          '{$contactData[2]}',
                          '{$contactData[3]}',
                          '{$contactData[4]}'
                           )

                         "); 
}
?>
```

These are the errors in import.php

Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in E:\wamp64\www\insert_from_csv\insert_from_csv\import.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined variable: contactList in E:\wamp64\www\insert_from_csv\insert_from_csv\import.php on line 18

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in E:\wamp64\www\insert_from_csv\insert_from_csv\import.php on line 18

I Deeply appreciate your help!

Comment: Isn't the first Warning about $fileContacts['tmp_name'] on line 6 being empty? Can you do something to make that Warning go away first?

Comment: I want to make that as my files will always have an empty file, but even if it's I would like the code to keep running. How would you suggest me to make it go away? Sorry I am a total newbie.

Comment: Ok 2 things. file_get_contents will return FALSE if the file is empty, and give a Warning if the 'filename'  cannot be found. I think in this case $fileContacts['tmp_name'] is getting a filename that doesnt exist. Print $fileContacts out below line 6, and see what you get when the Warning shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Below line 6, add a condition-

```
if($fileContacts !== false)
```

And put rest of the code inside that condition, so that it runs only if the file contents are not empty.

PS: The first Warning that you see is mostly because $fileContacts['tmp_name'] is getting a filename that doesn't exist. You can check if the filename exists or not using **is_file()**, which returns **true** if it does and **false** otherwise.

So combining both, the condition to use below line 6 would be-

```
if((is_file($fileContacts) == true) && ($fileContacts !== false))
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the code at all.
you can add a default value to your database and this will fix the issue.
try something like:

```
CREATE TABLE contacts (
contact_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
contact_given_name varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Not Provided',
contact_last_name varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Not Provided',
contact_phone varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Not Provided',
contact_email varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Not Provided',
contact_zip_code int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```